# Log_message codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-logging, error-log

I want to use log_message in Codeigniter but log_message does not write anything in the log file.

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;

$config['log_path'] = 'http://spsvn01/var/www/html/RAIDLOG/application/logs/';
```

And in my controller I write :

```
log_message('error','USER_INFO '.$user_info['email']);
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: need to be log_path and not 'log url', something like /var/www/...

Answer (score 7):

I would use the `FCPATH` constant which points to your application folder:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
$config['log_path'] = FCPATH . '/application/logs/';
```

Works fine on my end.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html

**Informational Messages**

```
log_message('info', 'USER_INFO ' . $user_info['email']);
```

**Error Messages**

```
log_message('error', 'USER_INFO ' . $user_info['email']);
```

Also, the logs folder must be writable. Do a `CHMOD 700` on the folder.

Comment: Yes my folder is chmod 777, and when i have 404 erreur a log file is created. But my log_message doesn't not write in it. :(

Comment: it should be $config['log_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/logs/';

Answer (score 3):

open the your_project_dir/application/config/config.php

In config file you'll find 3 default variables

```
$config['log_threshold']=0; 
$config['log_path'] = ''; 
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
```

1. $config['log_threshold'] accepts array (1, 2, 3) or single integer
   $config['log_path'] accepts path of log file (if you keep it blank the default path will be set and default path will be your_project_dir/application/logs/).
2. $config['log_file_extension'] accepts log file extension i.e html, txt etc. (if you keep it empty then default extension will be php)
3. Make sure your log path is write able.

**Error Status are already defined** In

your_project_dir/system/core/Log.php

```
protected $_levels = array('ERROR' => 1, 'DEBUG' => 2, 'INFO' => 3, 'ALL' => 4)
```

You've to assign array i.e for errors and info array(1, 2)
    Method log_message('', '') accepts 2 parameters. First parameter is level (i.e. ERROR or DEBUG or INFO or ALL) & second parameter is message.

**Example:**

```
log_message('ERROR', 'Custom error here.');
```

**Remember**
All default php errors will be part of the log if you assign

```
$config['log_threshold']=array(1)
```

**For custom Logs:** You've to add a new array element in your_project_dir/system/core/Log.php
i.e.

```
protected $_levels = array('ERROR' => 1, 'DEBUG' => 2, 'INFO' => 3, 'ALL' => 4, 'CUSTOM' => 5);
```

**Now you can call method as**

```
log_message('CUSTOM', 'Custom message here.'); // This will put just your custom messages in log file
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as simple like this:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;

$config['log_path'] = '/logs/';
```

Comment: You can leave `$config['log_path'] = '';` but the folder `application/logs/` must exist.

Comment: This exist my friend and the log_path is empty too but nothing is work :(

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but can help someone:
My codeigniter log has not be written, so I go to logs folder and execute this command:
sudo chown www-data logs/

Turn user www-data owner of the folder and then its work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32882612)