# How to compare two CodeIgniter query results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, if-statement

I have a table named SLA and some columns named harian(float), bulanan(float), progres(varchar). I need to update `progres` column to `green`, `yellow`, or `red` based on the value of the previous month.

Here is the code that I have tried

```
$id = $this->input->post('txtId');
$idminus1 = floatval($id) - 1;

$currentbulanan = $this->db->query("SELECT bulanan 
                                    FROM sla 
                                    WHERE id='$id'")
                ->row();

$previousbulanan = $this->db->query("SELECT bulanan 
                                    FROM sla 
                                    WHERE id='$idminus1'")
                ->row();

if ($currentbulanan > $previousbulanan) { 
    $progres = "green"; 
}
if ($currentbulanan < $previousbulanan) { 
    $progres = "red"; 
} 
if ($currentbulanan = $previousbulanan) { 
    $progres = "yellow"; 
}
```

I want to use `$progres` variable to update the `progres` column. I have checked that the result of the first query is greater than the result of the second query, but `$progres` is always `yellow`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to change `if ($currentbulanan > $previousbulanan)` to `if ($currentbulanan->bulanan > $previousbulanan->bulanan)`.

Comment: @ekad Thank you.. I have changed by adding **->bulanan** but the color still result _yellow_ even the value is greater than the first column..

And still curious on how to debug the code within JS.. Placing var_dump in Model shows nothing..

Comment: I'd suggest using `log_messages` function to debug. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389366/log-message-codeigniter) for an example. You'll need to set the `log_path` and `log_threshold` first. Use it like this: `log_message('debug', 'The value of $currentbulanan is: '. print_r($currentbulanan));`, then open your log file and check the result.

Comment: @ekad Thank you so much for all your responses, I will learn that method and check your link suggested, but here I have a Var_dump result by using non JS (copied my code outside JS) and I can now see the value of $currentbulanan :

object(stdClass)#21 (1) { ["bulanan"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: Ok, so now we know `$currentbulanan` is an object with `bulanan` property. Can you try `var_dump($currentbulanan->bulanan)`? If it's a string, then you'll need to convert it to float and also do the same with `$previousbulanan` variable. After that you can compare them using `>`.

Comment: @ekad Got it, it is now a string : string(7) "66.6667", going to convert it to float and compare both.. Soon let you the result.. Thanks

Comment: @ekad Please have a look at my edited question... Thanks

Comment: Looks like `if ($cbulanan = $pbulanan)` is the problem, for some reason it's always true. See [this code with =](http://codepad.org/nWE0tiqj), `$progres` is `yellow` even though `$cbulanan` is bigger than `$pbulanan`, but in [this code with ==](http://codepad.org/uLAIfe4W), `$progres` is `green`, which is correct.

Comment: Perfect! Solved by changing the operator = to ==, can you add your answer in the answer field, so I can accept it as the correct answer... Thank You @ekad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [CodeIgniter Generating Query Results Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

> row()
>
> This method returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row. The result is returned as an **object**.

Since you are using the `->row()` syntax to get `$currentbulanan` and `$previousbulanan` variables as below

```
$currentbulanan = $this->db->query("SELECT bulanan 
                                    FROM sla 
                                    WHERE id='$id'")
                ->row();

$previousbulanan = $this->db->query("SELECT bulanan 
                                    FROM sla 
                                    WHERE id='$idminus1'")
                ->row();
```

then the type of both `$currentbulanan` and `$previousbulanan` variables are **object**, so a comparison like this

```
if ($currentbulanan > $previousbulanan)
```

won't work the same as comparing two numbers. You need to convert the `bulanan` property of `$currentbulanan` and `$previousbulanan` to float

```
$cbulanan = floatval($currentbulanan->bulanan);
$pbulanan = floatval($previousbulanan->bulanan);
```

and then compare them like below

```
if ($cbulanan > $pbulanan)
```

The other problem is this syntax

```
if ($currentbulanan = $previousbulanan)
```

It will always be true, so `$progres` will always be set to `yellow`. According to [PHP Comparison Operators Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), the correct syntax to check equality is `==`.

Below is the complete modified code

```
$id = $this->input->post('txtId');
$idminus1 = floatval($id) - 1;

$currentbulanan = $this->db->query("SELECT bulanan 
                                    FROM sla 
                                    WHERE id='$id'")
                ->row();

$previousbulanan = $this->db->query("SELECT bulanan 
                                    FROM sla 
                                    WHERE id='$idminus1'")
                ->row();

// convert $currentbulanan->bulanan and $previousbulanan->bulanan to float
$cbulanan = floatval($currentbulanan->bulanan);
$pbulanan = floatval($previousbulanan->bulanan);

// compare the float values
if ($cbulanan > $pbulanan) { 
    $progres = "green"; 
}
if ($cbulanan < $pbulanan) { 
    $progres = "red"; 
} 
if ($cbulanan == $pbulanan) { // use the correct comparison operator
    $progres = "yellow"; 
}

// $progres will have the correct value here
```